# Google Tag Manager not reading dataLayer variable generated by gtag.js eventModel

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer, gtag.js

I need some help troubleshooting Google Tag Manager pulling in a gtag dataLayer eventModel variables.

I'm using gtag.js to send conversion data to a Google Analytics 4 property and have configured a gtag purchase event to send purchase conversion. The Google Tag Assistant is verifying that the dataLayer is set up correctly and returns this:

```js
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  eventModel: {
    transaction_id: "XXXXX",
    affiliation: "https://XXXX.com",
    value: "131.33",
    currency: "USD",
    shipping: "18.74",
    tax: "8.30",
    items: [
      {
        id: "3252",
        name: "XXXXXX",
        list_name: "Order",
        brand: "",
        category: "XXXX/XXXXX",
        variant: "",
        list_position: "1",
        price: "104.29",
        quantity: "1",
        SKU: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 4
})
```

I am attempting to add the Microsoft Advertising UET through the Google Tag Manager and utilize dataLayer data. It appears that the UET tags are firing correctly, but the purchase data variables are not being recognized.

In GTM, I have set up a User-Defined Variable to bring in the purchase amount and added the variable to the GTM UET Custom purchase tag.

> Name: dlv - eventModel.currency purchase

> Data Layer Variable Name: eventModel.currency

> Name: dlv - eventModel.value purchase

> Data Layer Variable Name: eventModel.value

Inside the UTE purchase tag I entered those variables as {{dlv - eventModel.currency purchase}} and {{dlv - eventModel.value purchase}}

Everything seems to be firing correctly, but the data for the variables are coming through as "undefined" or "null". So when the UET tag is fired, the script is leaving out the parameters for gv and gc.

In GTM, if I hard code a string to represent the "value" in place of the dataLayer variable, it inserts the parameter to the UET tag as it should.

Why are the eventModel.value and eventModel.currency variables not being pulled from the dataLayer by GTM?

[ScreenShot of UET Purchase tag details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wSl6.png)
(in this screenshot the currency was hard coded and is not a variable)

Comment: When the preview mode of Google Tag Manager. There would show the value that when purchase happened about these 2 parameters. You can check it first.

Comment: Yes.  And that value is "null" for the Microsoft UET.  I just installed the tag for the Facebook Pixel in GTM using the same dataLayer variable, and the purchase value is set to the proper value.